# Merge & display records from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-localdb

I have to create a view using 2 tables

**Table 1:**

```
TokenNumber     Symbol      InstType    LotSize     TickSize   sin              ClosePrice
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22              ACC         EQ          1           0.01       INE012A01025     0
25              ADANIENT    EQ          1           0.01       INE423A01024     0
```

**Table 2:**

```
TokenNumber     InstType   Symbol     ExpiryDate    CMToken    sorted_index
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
46676           FUTSTK     ACC        25-Jan-18     22         12
48205           FUTSTK     ACC        28-Dec-17     22         8
4820546676      FUTSTK     ACC        28-Dec-17     22         3
5361748205      FUTSTK     ACC        30-Nov-17     22         1
53618           FUTSTK     ADANIENT   30-Nov-17     25         3
4820646677      FUTSTK     ADANIENT   28-Dec-17     25         3
48206           FUTSTK     ADANIENT   28-Dec-17     25         8
46677           FUTSTK     ADANIENT   25-Jan-18     25         12
```

Thus to join both tables we have primary key of Table1(TokenNumber) in Table2(CMToken).

I have to show all the columns of both tables and records in a specific order(1st record from Table1  and next all records from Table2 where Table1.TokenNumber=Table2.CMToken).

New view with record order will be like:

```
TokenNumber  Symbol       InstType   LotSize    TickSize   Isin           ClosePrice    ExpiryDate      sorted_index
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                    
22           ACC          EQ         1          0.01       INE012A01025   0             NULL            NULL
46676        ACC          FUTSTK     NULL       NULL       NULL           NULL          25-Jan-18       0
48205        ACC          FUTSTK     NULL       NULL       NULL           NULL          28-Dec-17       1
4820546676   ACC          FUTSTK     NULL       NULL       NULL           NULL          28-Dec-17       2                                   
25           ADANIENT     EQ         1          0.01       INE423A01024   0             NULL            NULL
53618        ADANIENT     FUTSTK     NULL       NULL       NULL           NULL          30-Nov-17       0
4820646677   ADANIENT     FUTSTK     NULL       NULL       NULL           NULL          28-Dec-17       1
48206        ADANIENT     FUTSTK     NULL       NULL       NULL           NULL          28-Dec-17       3
46677        ADANIENT     FUTSTK     NULL       NULL       NULL           NULL          25-Jan-18       2
```

Please suggest the query.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output.

Comment: @zarruq- Edited and shared as asked

Comment: @Ashish Jaiswal - I changed my answer using your new data.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh --- Noted

Comment: @AshishJaiswal: Do the data of `table2` need to be sorted on the base of `TokenNumber`? and Do you need to populate `sorted_index` column at run time?

Answer (score 0):

Looking in to your sample data and output, I think you actually want to assign `sorted_index` = `NULL` to values of `table1` and `sorted_index` = `row_number()` partition by `CMToken` and order by `TokenNumber` starting from `0` to `table2`. After that you want to sort it by placing row of `table1` on top of associated rows of `table2` and among `table2` rows, you want to sort it by `row_number()`.

```
SELECT TokenNumber
    ,Symbol
    ,InstType
    ,LotSize
    ,TickSize
    ,Isin
    ,ClosePrice
    ,Expiry_Date
    ,sorted_index
FROM (
    SELECT TokenNumber
        ,Symbol
        ,InstType
        ,LotSize
        ,TickSize
        ,Isin
        ,ClosePrice
        ,NULL AS Expiry_Date
        ,NULL AS sorted_index
        ,TokenNumber AS CMToken
    FROM table1 t1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TokenNumber
        ,InstType
        ,Symbol
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,ExpiryDate
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CMToken ORDER BY TokenNumber
            ) - 1 AS sorted_index
        ,CMToken
    FROM table2 t2
    ) t
ORDER BY CMToken
    ,sorted_index
```

**Result:**

```
 +-------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+
| TokenNumber |  Symbol  | InstType | LotSize | TickSize |     Isin     | ClosePrice |     Expiry_Date     | sorted_index |
+-------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+
|          22 | ACC      | EQ       | 1       | 0,01     | INE012A01025 | 0          | NULL                | NULL         |
|       46676 | FUTSTK   | ACC      | NULL    | NULL     | NULL         | NULL       | 25.01.2018 00:00:00 | 0            |
|       48205 | FUTSTK   | ACC      | NULL    | NULL     | NULL         | NULL       | 28.12.2017 00:00:00 | 1            |
|  4820546676 | FUTSTK   | ACC      | NULL    | NULL     | NULL         | NULL       | 28.12.2017 00:00:00 | 2            |
|  5361748205 | FUTSTK   | ACC      | NULL    | NULL     | NULL         | NULL       | 30.11.2017 00:00:00 | 3            |
|          25 | ADANIENT | EQ       | 1       | 0,01     | INE423A01024 | 0          | NULL                | NULL         |
|       46677 | FUTSTK   | ADANIENT | NULL    | NULL     | NULL         | NULL       | 25.01.2018 00:00:00 | 0            |
|       48206 | FUTSTK   | ADANIENT | NULL    | NULL     | NULL         | NULL       | 28.12.2017 00:00:00 | 1            |
|       53618 | FUTSTK   | ADANIENT | NULL    | NULL     | NULL         | NULL       | 30.11.2017 00:00:00 | 2            |
|  4820646677 | FUTSTK   | ADANIENT | NULL    | NULL     | NULL         | NULL       | 28.12.2017 00:00:00 | 3            |
+-------------+----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/FSSP22534)**

Comment: Getting error as
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 34   
Invalid column name 'CMToken'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'CMToken'.

Comment: Actually I want to simply display all the column values in every row as if no data exist display as NULL else the value.

Comment: @AshishJaiswal: check the associated sql-server demo provided in answer. The query is simulated on your provided data. Perhaps you missed something.